# How to get specific property from another object?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a Firebase database in which I have few objects with their properties.

```
{
  "products": [{
    "sku": "70741",
    "name": "Name",
    "image": "name.png",
    "quantity": 12,
    "price": {
      "value": 2.10,
      "type": "simple"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "0": "2",
      "1": "4",
      "2": "2|1|3",
      "3": "1|2",
      "4": "2",
      "5": "6|7"
    }
  }
],
  "attributes": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "name1",
    "type": "type1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name2",
    "type": "type2"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name3",
    "type": "type1"
  }
],
  "attributesIdValue": [
    "companyName1|companyName2|companyName3|companyName4",
    "typeName1|typeName2|typeName3|typeName4",
    "address1|address2|address3|address4",
    "1|2|3",
    "country1|country2|country3|country4",
    "number1|number2|number3|number4"
  ]}
```

Key from the products.attributes should point to the attributes.id and attributesIdValue.id and value from products.attributes should point to the attributesIdValue depending on it's id and value.

How can I get something like this with vue.js:
`product.attributes.0` should display `companyName` of this product
`product.attributes.1` should display `typeName` of this product
`product.attributes.2` should display `address` of this product

`{{ product.price.value }}`works and displays the value, but I can't get to those attributes.

------- edit
In other words instead of above I want to have something like this:

```
  "products": [{
    "sku": "70741",
    "name": "Name",
    "image": "name.png",
    "quantity": 12,
    "price": {
      "value": 2.10,
      "type": "simple"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "attributes.0": "attributesIdValue.2",
      "attributes.1": "attributesIdValue.4",
      "attributes.2": "attributesIdValue.2|attributesIdValue.1|attributesIdValue.3",
      "attributes.3": "attributesIdValue.1|attributesIdValue.2",
      "attributes.4": "attributesIdValue.2",
      "attributes.5": "attributesIdValue.6|attributesIdValue.7"
    }
  }
],
  "attributes": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "name1",
    "type": "type1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name2",
    "type": "type2"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name3",
    "type": "type1"
  }
],
  "attributesIdValue": [
    "companyName1|companyName2|companyName3|companyName4",
    "typeName1|typeName2|typeName3|typeName4",
    "address1|address2|address3|address4",
    "1|2|3",
    "country1|country2|country3|country4",
    "number1|number2|number3|number4"
  ]}
```

which would output me the data inside of those.

Comment: Do you try to access `attributesIdValue` or `attributes`?

Comment: What is the relation btw product and `attributesIdValue`? How do you know which `typeName` (typeName1| typeName2| typeName3) you should return using `product.attributes.1`?

Comment: @SimonThiel both. `product.attributes` key (eg. "0": "2", where `0` is key and `2` is value) should get me a value from `attributes.id` which is `0` and `product.attributes` value should get me 2nd value from 0 position with is `companyName2`

@aquilesb I am not sure if that's clear what I say but there should be a bond between `product` and `attributes` and `attributesIdValue`.
`product.attributes.1` should return  `"1": "4",` So the key would get me `"id": 1, "name": "name2", "type": "type2"` and value would get me `typeName4` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

have you try JSON.parse(data);

Example:

```js
var data = '{ "products": [{ "sku": "70741", "name": "Name", "image": "name.png", "quantity": 12, "price": { "value": 2.10, "type": "simple" }, "attributes": { "0": "2", "1": "4", "2": "2|1|3", "3": "1|2", "4": "2", "5": "6|7" } } ], "attributes": [{ "id": 0, "name": "name1", "type": "type1" }, { "id": 1, "name": "name2", "type": "type2" }, { "id": 2, "name": "name3", "type": "type1" } ], "attributesIdValue": [ "companyName1|companyName2|companyName3|companyName4", "typeName1|typeName2|typeName3|typeName4", "address1|address2|address3|address4", "1|2|3", "country1|country2|country3|country4", "number1|number2|number3|number4" ]}';


obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(obj.attributes[0].name);
```

Comment: why would you enfore jquery on this? JSON.parse does not require jQuery

Comment: lol, i just remove it before you comment :D was imported by mistake

Comment: i see - it still seems you actually missed the real question here. The data is already an object. It's about dynamically accessing the right attribute values

Comment: Exactly as Frank said. Properties of those objects should refer to each other somehow.